# Realtime Anaglyphic viewport

Tags: 3d-view, stereoscopy

I've been trying to find if there is a way to achieve a realtime anaglyphic 3D viewport. I feel that this would be highly beneficial to a modeller by giving them a sense of depth with their model. I'm talking about one that would use the red and cyan glasses.
Are there plugins or anyway of achieving this?

Comment: Are you working on Windows?

Comment: Yep. 64 bit Windows 7

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/49105/2843

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The new [Multiview/Stereoscopy branch](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User%3aDfelinto/Stereoscopy) by Dalai Felinto supports many stereo formats (including anaglyph) in the viewport. You can find builds for it on [Graphicall.org](http://graphicall.org/?keywords=multiview)

Multiview is planned to be integrated into trunk by 2.68 or 2.69.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but the multiview branch is focused on rendering stereoscoping. There is a preview mode but you have to set up cameras and look through them. It doesn't support rotating the view in perspective mode.

Answer (score 9):

This feature was added to Blender in version 2.75a.

To enable it, you have to be in *Camera View*, which you can enable by pressing <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>. Optionally, you can lock the camera to your view by pressing selecting *View > Lock Camera to View* in the panel on the right-hand side of the 3D View (<kbd>N</kbd>).

**To enable the Anaglyphic viewport**, go to the *Render Layers* tab of the *Properties* panel, and check the *Views* checkbox. The default settings should be sufficient:

[image]

This is what it looks like:

[image]

For more detailed information, check out the relevant [Blender Manual](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/workflows/multiview.html) page.

Answer (score 5):

[iZ3D](http://www.iz3d.com/select_download) is a free driver that modifies the OpenGL library in your system to generate on the fly stereoscopic images of any OpenGL enabled application.

I've tested it with games, and is pretty realistic, in fact Need for Speed difficulty dropped to the floor using this driver.

[ILStero](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ilstereo/files/?source=navbar) is an open source project, haven't test it yet though.

You can use iZ3D to test you current Blender as is. Without having to built the source, so that you can see how it would improve your modeling skills.

Comment: wish it worked on linux, sounds pretty cool..

Answer (score 4):

This feature is currently in development as an experimental feature. Until it is has been finished, you can download a build of Blender with it at [this](http://www.graphicall.org/1005) website.

Note that it only works in Perspective view, but of course that is to be expected.

Comment: Wow, I learned something new again :D