# How can I do a monitoring/guard CCTV camera effect with blender?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, compositing-nodes, effects

How can I do a monitoring/guard CCTV camera effect like pictured below with blender?
[image]

Comment: What do you mean with this effect? Please describe it or add reference pictures.

Comment: If the answer is correct could you please mark is as Answered?

Answer (score 12):

If you are trying to achieve this effect on the right:

[image: before and after security cam effect]

Use the compositor and distort the source image with a Lens Distortion Node in projector mode. This can make it appear like a fisheye lens. Security cameras have a wide field of view. You could add horizontal lines to simulate an old tube monitor screen. Use a wood texture node and scale the x axis to 0 and the y or vertical axis to a very large value, then multiply it with the source, after distortion.

Also security or guard cameras operate in low light so you could remove the color with a  Hue Saturation Value node.

[image: distortion and texture effect]

[image: scale texture for lines]

For extra value you could add glare to the source image to blow out highlites and make a slightly blurry image, as these cameras often have poor optics. If you are making this effect in 3D I would still suggest using the compositor.

Comment: Wow! Nice one! +1 from me.

Comment: @mobile_beginner_2015 You may add an addictional distortion effect to it like in here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33660/how-to-achieve-this-effect-screen-tearing-glitch-in-blender-and-what-is-this

Comment: Thanks 3pointedit, this is indeed the effect I try to make

Comment: I'll up the anti... try generating a completely glitched piece of geometry along a roughly horizontal alignment. If it animates fast even better. Feed the normals to a displace node and intermittently glitch it, for that broken feed vibe, or do a vertical drag of the object to simulate a feed roll.

Comment: You mean like this other BStack answer? http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33660/how-to-achieve-this-effect-screen-tearing-glitch-in-blender-and-what-is-this?rq=1

Comment: Looks like. I did it for some video footage ways back. You can do a bubble distort (squished horizontal isosphere) or jaggy glitch (spikey cubes, densely squished horizontally) etc. It is pretty great when animated, surprisingly. Oh and if you do it, post an animated GIF from here for example @3pointedit http://gifmaker.me