# 1980s Chroma Interlacing effect

Tags: video-sequence-editor, compositing-nodes, edit-mode, video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lSTAWoER80Y

A Blender user in the U.K. made this recreation of old BBC schedule slides from the 80s. If you're watch it closely, there seems to be some fluttering (or, as the user calls it 'twitter') in the lettering, especially the yellow ones with the black outlines. Does anyone know how to achieve this effect as well as how to create an old NTSC or PAL filter

Comment: Also related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33660/how-to-achieve-this-effect-screen-tearing-glitch-in-blender-and-what-is-this?rq=1

Comment: And : https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39508/how-to-give-an-image-or-video-a-tv-screen-effect/39509#39509

Comment: And: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3491/dot-matrix-display-in-cycles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a black and white texture to be used as the interlace.

(I did this in blender with a texture on a plane, but it can be done with any image creation program)
[image]

Then use that image as a factor to combine different versions of the base image, that have been distressed with different filters.

[image]
(Click on the image to enlarge)

If you animate the values for the distortion filters or animate an inversion of the interlace texture you can maybe emulate NTSC in all of its glorious ugliness...

Comment: Will that manage to work for the chroma'd text as well?