# is there any way i can use crossview3d while editing?

Tags: 3d-view, stereoscopy

there is a 3d viewing technique calld crossview. you basically cross your eyes until 2 side by side images match up and create a single 3d image.

i always thought beaing able to view models in 3d while working on them would be helpfull, and when i discovered crossview i thought: i need to be able to view blender stuff like this.

what im looking for is a option to have 2 views of your obj open at the same time with a bit of offset and be able to turn them both while editing. i know you can just open other views and try to align them but as soon as i turn my view only one turns.

help would be greatly appreciated.
-laurin

BTW: for some crossview examples check out /r/crossview

Comment: well by doing that the differenc would be way to large, and i still wouldnt be able to turn both windows simultaniously. if you would have read the question you would have realized that i already tried that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for blender v2.79 you can try this:

- in the properties editor switch to 'Render Layers'
- than activate 'views'
- this defaults to 'Stereo 3D'
- now go to the main menu 'Window' there is a new option 'Set Stereo 3D' - click it
- here you can find multiple different ways - one is 'Side-by-Side'
- if you choose it you can additionally enable 'Cross-Eyed'

for this to work you have to enter Full-Screen mode (Alt+F11).

additional information can also be found in [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/43493/16634)
and in the [official documentation on multi-views](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/workflows/multiview/usage.html)

Comment: Your eyes/brain are going to break, I'd recommend getting anaglyph glasses, they're quite cheap and would work well for grayscale modeling.

Comment: @Leander i have used crossview continuesly for hours at a time mostly in the space exploration game SpaceEngine. after that it feels like i did workout with my eyes bu tno other effects.

Comment: @Laurin Amazing, exercise is healthy, don't forget to uncross your eyes once in a while.

Comment: @Leander dont worry,  i wont xD 

although i do have to say that i didnt need to train for that.

and i find it very amazng that it feels so natural to me.